# Percent change based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiNWZ.jpg)What am trying to do is calculate the percentage change from Monday to Friday. Also sometime the week begins on tuesday, as show in the photo

```
Data = { ‘Date’ : [‘8/24/2018’, ‘8/23/2018’, ‘8/22/2018’, ‘8/21/2018’, ‘8/20/2018’, ‘8/17/2018’, ‘8/16/2018’], “Day of Week’ : [ ‘Friday’, ‘Thursday’, ‘Wednesday’, ‘Tuesday’,’Monday’, ‘Friday’, ‘Thursday’], ‘Price’ : [120.3, 121.2, 119.98,120.03,123.6,120.5,122.5] }

def week_pct_chng (row): 
       If row[‘Day of Week’] == “Friday” and row[‘Day of Week’].shift(1) == ‘Monday’:
              Return ( the percentage of Monday to Friday) 
       Else: 
              Return(‘NaN’)
```

I don’t know what the put in the return. 
What my answer should be -.026

Please help thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate percent_change on the whole `Price` column using `pct_change`, then just find where you are interested:

## Setup:

```
Data = { 'Date' : ['8/24/2018', '8/23/2018', '8/22/2018', '8/21/2018', '8/20/2018', '8/17/2018', '8/16/2018'], 'Day of Week' : [ 'Friday', 'Thursday', 'Wednesday', 'Tuesday','Monday', 'Friday', 'Thursday'], 'Price' : [120.3, 121.2, 119.98,120.03,123.6,120.5,122.5] }

df = pd.DataFrame(Data)
```

## Code:

```
df['percent_change'] = df.Price.pct_change()

df.loc[(df['Day of Week'] == 'Friday') & (df['Day of Week'].shift() == 'Monday'), 'percent_change']
```

Which returns your value as a Series:

```
5   -0.025081
Name: percent_change, dtype: float64
```

Comment: it works for this because the data is small. When i try it on a data thats 1000+ value big, with multiple 'Mondays' and 'Fridays,' i get : " Series([], Name: Percent Change, dtype: float64 "

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faARh.png)

I was able to get calculate the percent change from Monday through Friday, however the problem that i have is sometime the week begins on Tuesday.